# Changing the opacity of RichEditBox SelectionHighlightColor is not working in uwp?

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

changing the opacity of the RichEdibBox's SelectionHighlightColor is not working,
`this.editor.SelectionHighlightColor.Opacity = 0.1;`
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to change the opacity for the selected Text color? The Highlight color is used to indicate the text and make it more obvious to the user which content has been selected.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, he is asking about how to change the selectionHighlight color's opacity ?If he try's to change the opacity by RichEditBox.SelectionHighlightColor.Opacity = 0.1,it didn't work !!

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Does it make sense to you?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT understood what you said but i had requirement of reducing opacity

Comment: As I mentioned, the opacity for the selected text can't be changed, this is by design.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is expected, you can't change the Opacity of the SelectionHighlightColor for **RichEditBox** and **TextBox**. This is by design. The document doesn't mentioned this but I've talked with the team about this.